# Confusion about Google Play Games Auto-matching behaviour

Tags: google-play-games

I have a turn-based multiplayer game developed with Google Play Games.

I'm just in the process of getting auto-matching to work, and I noticed a bit strange thing that I'm not sure if it's my (messy) coding, or just the way Google Play Games works...

Let's say player A starts an auto-matched game. Makes his turn, and the turn is pushed to the Google's Server.. now, player B starts an auto-matched game, and joins the player A's game.

Everything working so far.

However, I just tried to start ANOTHER auto-matched game, either with player A or B - while player A & B have a match already going on, and I noticed that my game jumps to the previous game.

Am I messing something up (very possible), or is it not possible to start two simultaneous games via auto-matching (with invitations it is very much possible).

Answer (score 0):

@fluxi maybe there is some adjustments to be done to prevent your app to jump to the previous game. According to **[Developer's Guide for Turn-base Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/turnbasedMultiplayer#implementing_a_quick_match)**,

> When creating a match with auto-matching, Google Play games services
>    might return a match that is already in progress. This occurs when the
>    match configuration sent by your game to Google Play games services
>    has the same configuration as an **existing match that is underway** (that
>    is, the other player has already taken a turn). Because Google Play
>    games services might return a match that is in progress, be sure to
>    check for game data in the returned match object.

Maybe create a try catch and if invited player(auto-matching) is currently in an existing match alert the user (the one who send the invite) with a personal error message like "Failed to create game, invited player is already in match, Please try again".